# Aggregate function for corresponding row

Tags: postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have the following table with a combined primary key of `id` and `ts` to implement historization:

```
create table "author" (
  "id"     bigint     not null,
  "ts"     timestamp  not null default now(),
  "login"  text       unique not null,
  primary key ("id", "ts")
);
```

Now I am interested only in the latest `login` value. Therefor I group by `id`:

```
select "id", max("ts"), "login" from "author" group by "id";
```

But this throws an error: `login` should be used in an aggregate function.

`id` and `max("ts")` uniquely identify a row because the tupple (id, ts) is the primary key. I need the `login` which matches the row identified by `id` and `max("ts")`.

I can write a sub-select to find the `login`:

```
select ao."id", max(ao."ts"), 
       (select ai.login from "author" ai
        where ao."id" = ai."id" and max(ao."ts") = ai.ts)
from "author" ao
group by "id";
```

This works but it is quite noisy and not very clever, because it searches the whole table although searching the group would be sufficient.

Does an aggregate function exist, which avoids the sub-select and gives me the remaining `login`, which belongs to `id` and `max("ts")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to identify the correct key to get the value you like from the table.

The correct key is:

```
 select "id", max("ts") from "author" group by "id";
```

And using this to get the login you want:

```
 select a1."id", a1.ts, a1.login
 from "author" a1
      inner join (select "id", max("ts") maxts, "login" from "author" group by "id") a2
      ON a1.id = a2.id AND a1.ts = a2.maxts;
```

Alternatively using window functions:

```
 SELECT "id", "ts", login
 FROM (
      select "id", "ts", CASE WHEN "ts" = max("ts") OVER (PARTITION BY "id") THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as isMax, "login" from "author" group by "id"
       ) dt
 WHERE isMax = 1
```

There's a few other ways to skin this cat, but that's basically the gist.